# Xamarin forms: How to remove the selected item from FlowListView?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to remove the selected picture when clicks a cross image. For that, I added a cross image on top of the image and added the tapped event. I am showing the images in `FlowListView`.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" x:Name="listItems" 
                    SeparatorVisibility="None"
                    HasUnevenRows="false" RowHeight="100" >
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackLayout
                Orientation="Vertical">

                        <Image 
                    Source="ic_close.png"
                    HeightRequest="20"
                            ClassId="{Binding .}"
                    WidthRequest="20">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="RemoveImage"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>

                        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HeightRequest="100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Source="{Binding .}"  Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        </Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
   ObservableCollection<string> _images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    //List<string> _images = new List<string>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

         //Change List and add ObservableCollection here
         MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, ObservableCollection<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelected", (s, images) =>
        {
            listItems.FlowItemsSource = images;
            _images = images;
        });
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, List<string>>(this, "ImagesSelected");
    }

    public void RemoveImage(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
         var i = (Image)sender;
        _images.Remove(i.ClassId);
    }
  }
}
```

**Anybody, please suggest a way to remove that image from FlowListview?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ObservableCollection and add the image into it when rececing those images

Like this :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing(); :) 

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelected", (s, images) =>
        {
            for (int i =0;i< images.Count;i++)
            {
                _images.Add(images[i]);
            }
            listItems.FlowItemsSource = _images;
        });
    }
```

And then remove that selected image after tapping on the image .

```
public void RemoveImage(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    string obj = image.BindingContext as string;
    _images.Remove(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make your collection an `ObservableCollection`

```
ObservableCollection<string> _images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Second, add the image name to the otherwise unused `ClassID` property

```
<Image ClassID="{Binding .}" ... />
```

Finally, in your `RemoveImage`

```
public void RemoveImage(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var i = (Image)sender;
    images.Remove(i.ClassID);
}
```

Comment: Edited the question with your suggestions. Now the selected pictures from the gallery are not showing in the UI.

Comment: I am using `flowlistview` for showing the images in UI. f`lowlistview` is ICollection, so is there any other modification pending?

Comment: I am doing a feture of Selecting Multiple Images From Gallery. https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: After selecting the pictures from the gallery I need the remove a picture feature. Can you please help me?